# Issue with mongodb document limit

Tags: mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I am using mongodb 3.0.2 and when I run "top" command :

```
> db.runCommand( { top: 1 } )
```

I got the following error message:

> 2015-06-01T16:36:52.886+0900 E QUERY    Error: error: {
>         "$err" : "BSONObj size: 46060490 (0x2BED3CA) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB)",
>         "code" : 10334
>       }
>           at Error ()
>           at DBQuery.next (src/mongo/shell/query.js:259:15)
>           at DBCollection.findOne (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:189:22)
>           at DB.runCommand (src/mongo/shell/db.js:58:41)
>           at (shell):1:4 at src/mongo/shell/query.js:259

It means that I can't monitor any longer, doesn't it? Can you guys show me the way out, please.

Some additional info:

- DB size: 143.996GB - with wiredtiger enable.
- Replication set enable.
- No profiling.

Comment: Are you issuing the command against the admin database? If not, you could try `db.adminCommand("top")` or  run the command `use admin` first before `db.runCommand( { top: 1 } )`. Example [**here**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/top/#example).

Comment: By the way, understand that [**top**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/top/#top) is an administrative command that returns usage statistics for each collection and provides amount of time, in microseconds, used and a count of operations. From your question title I think you are looking for the [**`limit`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#limit-the-number-of-documents-to-return) method to limit the number of documents in the result set.

Comment: Thanks you for your help, i have done exactly as the example. But the issue still there. I have more than 100 collections, maybe it is too many of them.
From the title i think this issue is a limitation of mongo: could not query  more than 16MB documents.